# Finetuning Overscan/Underscan on ATI Radeon

Tags: hdmi, amd-radeon, tv, amd-catalyst, overscan

I have a Radeon R7 200 series graphics card on my PC, and i have just connected a TV (Samsung 37") to its HDMI port, and im currently working with the overscan/underscan settings. My TV is setup to 16:9 mode (it also has a "screen fit" setup that makes it just right without any overscan, but when i change to it, the letters begin to "bleed out" - for example, a "V" has a little tail on its edge, so it seems like a wannabe "y" - , so it does not look sharp).

The thing is, with the CCC slider, i have managed to set it up, but when i set it up to 4% underscan, it goes a little over the border, but if i change it to 5%, it goes under the border and makes a little black frame around the image.

The question is: Is there a way (be it SW, HW, registry, etc) to finetune the % (for example, 4.5%), so i can make it "just right"? I havent found a question that addresses this concern, so i decided to ask it here.